# inline styling inside php tags

Tags: php, styles, inline-styles

I am working on a website in which I want to do inline style **for the text coming from php tags**.

The code for that is:

```
   <p class="mb-0">hello world, <?php echo strtolower($data['client']->client_details->first_name);?></p>
```

The above code is producing the following output:

`hello world, Mike`

The word **Mike** is coming from the database and I have to make it orange color.

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in this code `<?php echo strtolower($data['client']->client_details->first_name);?></p>` so that the text coming out from it is orange or any other which I want to select.

Comment: May I know the reason why my questions is downvoted.

Comment: I didn't downvote but it is simple HTML and CSS and probably shouldn't be tagged with PHP.

Comment: I didn't dv either, but I believe it's because you can do whatever you want: It's completely open-ended, and depends on you. Is this the only thing that's going to be orange on the page? Sure, inline it? Want your code to look a bit neater? Put it in CSS.

Comment: @Lachie Ohk thanks for letting me know. Any idea how can I do inline-styling for it ?

Comment: <?php echo '<span class="YOURCLASS">'.strtolower($data['client']->client_details->first_name).'</span>';?>

and YOURCLASS you can style you like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've just put all your output's into a singular style controlled by the `<p>` tag. You could do this styling in multiple ways: in the PHP echo (using HTML and inline CSS) or using straight HTML and CSS (preferred method).

The method I will provide here is HTML and inline CSS. This can change by adding a class to your stylesheet with the inline style added.

```
 <p class="mb-0">hello world, <span style="color: orange;"><?php echo strtolower($data['client']->client_details->first_name);?></span></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not a question of your php code directly. You could add inline CSS styles like this:

```
<p class="mb-0">hello world, <span style="color: orange;"><?php echo strtolower($data['client']->client_details->first_name);?></span></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it inside an inline container (like ) , then add a CSS class to make it orange:

```
<style>
    .orange {
        color: orange;
    }
</style>
<p class="mb-0">hello world, <span class="orange"><?php echo strtolower($data['client']->client_details->first_name);?></span></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the colour to be configurable from PHP, you can just echo out the colour in an inline `style` attribute: `<span style="color: <?php echo $colour;?>;">`

```
<?php $colour = "orange"; ?>
<p class="mb-0">hello world, <span style="color: <?php echo $colour;?>;"><?php echo strtolower($data['client']->client_details->first_name);?></span></p>
```

This can be seen working **[here](https://3v4l.org/IfNtc)**.